# Merging multiple images to generate a video using Transloadit

Tags: web-services, api, transloadit

I have successfully combined a single image and a audio file and generated a video using Transloadit.

> Can I use transloadit to combine multiple images, with or without audio into video ?

Here is the api link : [API](https://transloadit.com/docs/conversion-robots#video-merge)

Any help would be useful. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(talking as a Transloadit founder) You can't at the moment. However we expect to ship this feature late October 2014. We'll post announcements on twitter/blog.